# Selecting the desired data structure

Tags: java

I need to solve task. I have ascrtact class employees and two classes of inheritors (class of employees with fixed salary and class with hourly pay). In the abstract class I need to create abstract method to calculate the average monthly salary. Additional tasks include sorting the average monthly salary in descending order and deduce an employee ID, the average monthly wage. Please, tell me that it is better to use ? Collections or array ?

Comment: with arrays you would need to write own logic, go for collections. may be sorted list for average salary.

Comment: collection can help you to write simpler code.

Comment: i think that the best choise is Map, because i need to deduce ID ? But at the same time I need to sort value ? How I can sort key and value in Collection ?

Comment: I had not yet written, because I do not understand how best to accomplish the task.

Comment: You can do-it in any way but using Collections give you more flexibility because java Collection framework has large no of functions to do different operations.Your code is more customized than array oriented code.In case of array it will be fast and nothing more...

Comment: How can I sort the data by key ?